# "Dream, dreamt" and "learn, learnt" irregular verbs: correct or not?

Tags: verbs, past-tense, irregular, variants

Often when I am writing emails or any other documents, I would like to use the irregular forms of *dream* (*dreamt*) or *learn* (*learnt*). But the computer spellcheckers always underline these words as being “wrong”, including right now on this very question that I am writing !

However, I know I have seen the words before. Don't know where, but surely I don’t have a habit of making up words of my own. Also, I believe that checking [the Using English website](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/irregular-verbs/) confirms that the words do exist and should be correct?

Can someone please clear up what this is all about, and why (some?) spellchecking software treats *dreamt* and *learnt* as incorrect?

Comment: Could you provide some more information on your spellchecker, since mine accepts both (and it is set to BrE)...

Comment: You must have an American spell-checker (even though these past tenses are used by a number of Americans, as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this article at Oxford Dictionaries online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/learnt-vs-learned), there is a difference between the spelling in American and British English:

> These are alternative forms of the past tense and past participle of the verb learn. ‘Learnt’ is more common in British English, and ‘learned’ in American English. There are a number of verbs of this type (burn, dream, kneel, lean, leap, spell, spill, spoil etc.). They are all irregular verbs, and this is a part of their irregularity.

So you may want to check which dialect of English your spellchecker is using.

Comment: Something still smells fishy. *Dreamt* is perfectly common even in North American English.  And I don’t get any red squiggles under *learnt* when I use it, even though my settings are configured for cisatlantic English usage.

Comment: @tchrist - That is indeed fishy... mine accepts both forms as well. As an aside, I _do_ get squigglies for _spellchecker_ and not for _spell-checker_...

Comment: @tchrist I suspect *dreamt* is only common in North America because of Shakespeare. And *learnt* is only common here in the American South. I do get squiggles for *dreamt* and *learnt* and the spellings look archaic to me.

Comment: The *spellchecker* matter is an interesting one. In general, British and Irish publishers retain hyphens in “new” compound words longer than North American ones do, but I am rather surprised yours deemed it “wrong”. I know you know better, but the OP’s question does make me wonder how it is that so many people have come to trust the judgement of a dodgy program over their own good sense. As a complete aside, *dreamt* is virtually unique in English in that it ends in *‑mt*.  The only other word that comes close is that the rare *transumpt* was sometimes spelt *transumt* during the 17ᵗʰ century.

Comment: @tchrist - With me (and many others) not being native English speaker(s), it shouldn't be hard to understand why a dodgy program can place doubt over oneself =)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I find your “Shakespeare theory” summarily unlikely, given that never once did the Bard pen the word *undreamt* anywhere that we know of. He did, however, quite notably write in Act IV Scene 4 of *The Winter’s Tale* the following: “A cause more promising /
Than a wild dedication of yourselves /
To unpath’d waters, **undream’d** shores, most certain /
To miseries enough; no hope to help you, /
But as you shake off one to take another;” — so I don’t have any idea why you mentioned him.

Comment: @tchrist *There are more things in heaven and earth, Horatio,
Than are **dreamt** of in your philosophy.*
- Hamlet (1.5.167-8), Hamlet to Horatio

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Oh right: I was only searching for instances of *undreamt* not of *dreamt*. While it is true that Shakespeare — the man who never spelt his own name the same way twice in a row :) — indeed wrote *dreamt* fourteen times, it is also true and perhaps more important to notice that he also wrote *dreamed* twice as well as *dream’d* ***seventeen*** times, doubtless because Emerson’s hobgoblins of foolish inconsistency had not yet been invented during the Elizabethan Era. I therefore reckon his overall final tally stands at 19 to 14. :)

Comment: @tchrist Does that vary by folio?

Comment: @tchrist The bard appears to have cared not for spelling. [*Dreamed*](http://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/views/plays/play_view.php?WorkID=muchado&Act=2&Scene=1&Scope=scene&LineHighlight=717#717) and [*dreamt*](http://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/views/plays/play_view.php?WorkID=muchado&Act=1&Scene=2&Scope=scene&LineHighlight=305#305) in Much Ado about Nothing.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Right: spelling just wasn’t a “thing” for him. I recommend we all follow his *dreamt*-vs-*dreamed* variability.  [Maybe check here](http://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/) but that’s but a single spelling per work, not multiple versions thereof.

Comment: The bard was not alone. Nobody cared for speling. Spelling was as individual and variable as handwriting. Standard spelling didn't become a mass memorization scheme until much later. Now we use it as a class marker.